# Javadoc documentation render in place. Can one see pretty-print documentation in IDE?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse-plugin, javadoc, doxygen

Is there a plugin to Eclipse (or Visual Studio) which renders javadoc (or doxygen) in place, i.e. there is a pretty print in code instead of displaying javadoc source as comment?

By default it is possible just to fold method body. It could be usefull to have a toggle: full source, source and rendered javadoc, pure rendered javadoc.

Said plugin could generate something looking like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, maybe the Javadoc view (ALT+SHIFT+Q J) would be close to your requirements. On the other hand. If pretty printing for javadoc would be included in the editor. How would you change the javadoc?

Comment: Edit after switching the toggle: full source, i.e. source code and javadoc as code comment. The whole idea is to have documentation by default displayed in code inline, without need to open any popups or additional windows. We can take a look at this extension to Visual Studio [Image Insertion](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/793d16d0-235a-439a-91df-4ce7c721df12). They have whole images in code, maybe there is some extension rendering Rich-text or doxygen in place?

Comment: I think an editor should focus on the code as it is written and maintained by the coder. So extra's like the image insertion of visual studio detracts the coder from what they are doing. An extra view like the one in eclipse keeps the focus correct. And with a mouse over on the method, you also get to see the rendered javadocs. So, no need for extra fancy stuff in the editor itself.

Comment: I'd like this feature so I can easier browse someone else's source code, and review my own javadoc and source in one. And sure would be something you'd toggle on and off so you can edit.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. In eclipse, just open or select the javadoc view and go to your own method